# How to solve an ODE in Sturm-Liouville form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am attempting to solve the following ODE:

$\frac{d}{dz} \bigg[F'(z) \bigg(\frac{z-1}{z}\bigg)^2\bigg] = \frac{2(z-1)F(z)}{z^4}$

with the conditions that both $F(z)$ and $F'(z)$ approach 0 as $z$ approaches $\pm \infty$.

I have tried integrating both sides over different domains but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given equation has the structure $$(F'(z)u(z)^2))'=u(z)v(z)F(z)$$ with $u(z)=\frac{z-1}z=1-\frac1z$ and $v(z)=\frac{2}{z^3}$. This expands under the product rule to (wherever $u(z)\ne 0$, $z\ne 0$) $$F''(z)u(z)+2F'(z)u'(z)=v(z)F(z).$$ Now you will also find the terms on the left side in the second derivative of a product,
$$
(F(z)u(z))''=F''(z)u(z)+2F'(z)u'(z)+u''(z)F(z)=(u''(z)+v(z))F(z)
$$
and with $u''(z)=-\frac{2}{z^3}$ one gets  $u''(z)+v(z)=0$ so that
$$
F(z)\frac{z-1}z=Az+B.
$$
But $$F(z)=\frac{Az^2+Bz}{z-1}$$ has no non-trivial solutions with $F(\pm\infty)=0$, so that for the given conditions $F(z)=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: I think the second last line should be $u'' + v = 0$ not $u + v = 0$

Comment: Yes of course. Thank you.

Comment: @Lutzt. I agree with your conclusion. +1